# Give an algorithm that finds an arbitrary item X in a binary heap using at most roughly 3N/4 comparisons

Tags: data-structures, binary-heap

This question is in the book of Mark Allen Weiss in exerice 10 in chapter 6 about heaps.

Could you please help me to solve this problem?
[image]

I was able to find a solution that gives a 3N/4 comparison in most cases, but there is cases where my algorithm do N comparasions.

In my solution, I start from the level before last and I check if I have to go up (if X < minimum of the level) which gives N/2 comparisons, or I have to go down (if X > maximum of the level) which gives 3N/4 comparisons. But when X is between the min and max of the penultimate level I can't decide whether to go up or down which gives N comparisons.

Answer (score -1):

I contacted the author of the manual (Mark Allen Weiss) and he informed me that the solution is in the article titled: [The Complexity of Heaps](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/139404.139483) written by Svante Carlsson and Jingsen Chen.

Comment: Although links can be useful, the answer should include the solution. If you don't have it, then it should be just a comment or edit to your question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).